# IsInViewport change img to gif once

Tags: jquery, image, scroll, viewport, gif

I'm completely stuck on this problem.

My goal is to change an img to a gif, once the img is within viewport.

I've used the IsInViewport library: https://github.com/zeusdeux/isInViewport and implemented the following code on http://www.verticalstrategy.com/agile_strategy/ (see below).

Can anyone spot why my boolean doesn't seem to work and the gif is loading every time you scroll within the viewport?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

    gifset = false;

    if (gifset == false) {

        $(window).scroll(function () {

            $(".for-large-device .wpb_wrapper .vc_single_image-wrapper img:in-viewport").attr('src', "http://www.verticalstrategy.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/agileStrategy_Landscape-1.gif?");
            $(".for-large-device .wpb_wrapper .vc_single_image-wrapper img:in-viewport").attr('srcset', "http://www.verticalstrategy.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/agileStrategy_Landscape-1.gif?");
            $(".for-small-device .wpb_wrapper .vc_single_image-wrapper img:in-viewport").attr('src', "http://www.verticalstrategy.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/agileStrategy_portrait-1.gif?");
            $(".for-small-device .wpb_wrapper .vc_single_image-wrapper img:in-viewport").attr('srcset', "http://www.verticalstrategy.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/agileStrategy_portrait-1.gif?");

            if ($(".for-large-device .wpb_wrapper .vc_single_image-wrapper").is(':in-viewport')) {
                gifset = true;
            }

        });
    };
});
```

Comment: On your live link, the console says `missing ) after argument list - Agile.js:25` and `jQuery(...).live is not a function - (index):2072`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what your code does, in natural language:

- Wait for the page to be ready
- Once the page is ready:
- . Declare gifset, set it to false.
- . If gifset is false [hint: always] do this:
- .. Register a scroll listener
- .. ...

The problem here is that you only check the gifset variable right after setting it. It can never change in that scope.

If you move the variable check to inside the scroll listener, it should work. Here, I check if gifset is true and exit, otherwise perform the action as before:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

    gifset = false;

    $(window).scroll(function () {

        if(gifset) {
            return;
        }

        $(".for-large-device .wpb_wrapper .vc_single_image-wrapper img:in-viewport").attr('src', "http://www.verticalstrategy.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/agileStrategy_Landscape-1.gif?");
        $(".for-large-device .wpb_wrapper .vc_single_image-wrapper img:in-viewport").attr('srcset', "http://www.verticalstrategy.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/agileStrategy_Landscape-1.gif?");
        $(".for-small-device .wpb_wrapper .vc_single_image-wrapper img:in-viewport").attr('src', "http://www.verticalstrategy.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/agileStrategy_portrait-1.gif?");
        $(".for-small-device .wpb_wrapper .vc_single_image-wrapper img:in-viewport").attr('srcset', "http://www.verticalstrategy.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/agileStrategy_portrait-1.gif?");

        if ($(".for-large-device .wpb_wrapper .vc_single_image-wrapper").is(':in-viewport')) {
            gifset = true;
        }

    });
});
```

A better solution would be to unregister the listener, once the image source has been updated, as every scroll will keep resulting in a function call until that happens (even if it is a short function call it is unnecessary overhead).